# How to reduce MacOS X Leopard footprint?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, osx-leopard, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you remove from a default os x install?](https://superuser.com/questions/6831/what-do-you-remove-from-a-default-os-x-install)

Hello.

Is it any guides available how to reduce an HDD space occupied by Mac OS X? Languages i don't use etc.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this question: <http://superuser.com/questions/6831/what-do-you-remove-from-a-default-os-x-install/7405#7405>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For languages that you no longer uses and **have no plan of using again** you can use the following software: [Monolingual](http://monolingual.sourceforge.net/)

It frees up a few gigabytes of space.

You can also see what is using up all your space by using a program called [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/)

You could also upgrade to Snow Leopard which gets rid of 10-20GB of bulk that Leopard takes up. I only recommend this if you have no customization on your system because it will break these installs.